# неправильно сравниваются значения input.value и null

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

У меня на странице есть форма заявки, она реализована 3 полями ввода (input), мне нужно проверить, ввёл ли пользователь данные в эти поля, когда я проверяю, пустое ли значение в поле инпут, код пишет что оно не пустое, хотя это не так.

```
let briefVInputDataName = nameInputBriefV.value
let briefVInputDataEmail = emailInputBriefV.value
let briefVInputDataPhone = numberInputBriefV.value
if ((briefVInputDataName != null) && ((briefVInputDataEmail != null) || (briefVInputDataPhone != null))) {
```

я пробовал сравнивать input.value с null, undefined, пустой строкой, нулём, со значением другого инпута, который специально для этого создал, то есть там 100% пустое значение, также я пробовал использовать !== вместо !=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неверно ожидаете равенство пустой строки и null

```js
console.log('' == null)
```

в вашем случае нужно проверить на ввел ли значение, а не null

```js
let briefVInputDataName = nameInputBriefV.value

console.log(briefVInputDataName != null)

console.log(briefVInputDataName != '')
```

```html
<input id="nameInputBriefV" type="input" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот как можно проверить на пустую строку:

```js
const str = '';

if (!str) {
  console.log('Пустая строка');
}
```

```js
const str = '';

if (str.length === 0) {
  console.log('Пустая строка');
}
```

```js
const str = '';

if (str === '') {
  console.log('Пустая строка');
}
```